# Do we really want to delete undecidable answers, even if they were declared non-competing?

Tags: discussion, noncompeting, deleted-answers

The problem emerged with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143046/66833) answer (deleted, and so invisible for users with less than 10k reputation)

The most relevant win criteria of the puzzle is the algorithmic complexity of the solution.

An answer using Mathematica was posted, making the algorithmic complexity of the solution depending heavily on the internal algorithms used by this software. These are not enough well known, and practically unknowable, because Mathematica is closed-source software.

However, the solution seemed a quite interesting one for me, and maybe also for others (it got multiple upvotes).

Accepting the situation, the poster declared the solution as non-competing.

Despite that, it was deleted by community votes.

I think, also non-competing or undecidable answers improve the site. However, it would be probably not useful to have a large mass of non-competing, unanswerable answers. Furthermore, the primary goal of the site may be to collect mainly competing answers to the puzzles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes

Non-competing doesn't allow an answer to do what it wants, and not meet the questions specifications. If a question has a specific scoring system, answers whose scores can't be calculated shouldn't be marked non-competing, they should be removed from the question.

In short, if I posted an answer to the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) question that didn't display `Hello, World!`, is it a valid answer? No. Can it be marked non-competing? No. To [quote Dennis](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/66833),

> Marking an answer as ***non-competing*** does not exempt it from being invalid.

The Mathematica answer, while being interesting, did not meet the answer specification, and, [per our rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/66833) it should have been deleted. This also applies to any other answers which, while accomplishing the task at hand, can't be scored.

Comment: What if it actually prints hello world, and it may fulfill the criteria, but nobody can check it for sure?

Comment: @peterh what criteria?

Comment: The win criteria of the question. In this specific case, the algorithmic complexity of the solution couldn't be determined, although it solved the problem.

Comment: @peterh if it can't provably complete the task, and can't have an objective, determinable score, it isn't a valid answer

Comment: A better analogy would be a 'Hello, World!' program where for some reason you can't possibly determine the byte count (think of a tokenized language like TI-BASIC, but then one that does not reveal how many bytes each token is). It performs the task, but you cannot determine the score.

Comment: Of course, if the question explicitly allows non-competing answers, they should be allowed [per this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12987/60043).