# Remember IP5 challenges? Why not BP10?

Tags: discussion

I would like to propose a set of 10 basic challenges meant to be an intro to code golf. It would cover pop-con, golf, bowling, challenge, koth (iffy), CnR and other types. They would be listed on the FAQ as beginner challenges. All of them allow any language to compete even new ones. What do you think?

(Beginner Programming 10)

Comment: Good luck posting a popcon challenge that doesn't get closed ;)

Comment: It was 1P5, not IP5.

Answer (score 3):

Once a CnR is over, it's over. There's no point in posting more cop answers if the robbers already left. A similar problem exists with KotH, as posting an answer and never getting a score is rather frustrating.

Pop cons and code bowling are probably the last challenge types which we should shove in a new user's face. Writing a proper pop con is rather hard, and for the good ones, so is writing an answer. I'm not convinced writing a good code bowling contest is possible at all.

That leaves code golf and code challenges. Unfortunately, these can't be too difficult if part of a beginner's tutorial, and the easy ones get answered rather quickly in hundreds of languages, so unless the beginner knows rather obscure languages, there's nothing left to do for them.

> All of them allow any language to compete even new ones.

[We already allow that for all challenges.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/12012)

Comment: So perhaps only allow newer users (<6 months on here?) to answer?

Comment: That sounds like an artificial solution to an artificial problem. Constantly bumping challenges to the front page that the vast majority of users isn't allowed to answer is a bad idea. Also, how do you define "on"? And how to you propose to enforce this rule I guarantee many users will miss?

Comment: Good point. I just remember feeling shut down when I first join as I could never answer.