# Answers still marked as "non-competing"

Tags: discussion, code-golf

The community [has decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/61384) that answers in newer languages can now compete in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (they were previously required to be marked as non-competing). However, now and then I will still come across an answer that hasn't been updated with this rule yet, so it is still marked as non-competing.

I have been both the sender and recipient of comments asking to remove the non-competing note from a submission, and I am wondering whether these comments are necessary.

Should we try to get permission from the poster before editing? Should we just edit it out without notifying them? Or should we just leave them?

Answer (score 14):

Editing the text out yourself is fine, but don't get too carried away, lest you bump a lot of old challenges to the front page. The general rule of thumb for doing mass edits is to only edit content on around 5 questions per day to prevent drowning out new content with the bumps. I'd also suggest leaving a comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: If there are multiple answers that need editing on a single question, it's best to do them all at once so it only needs to be bumped once.

Comment: @Laurel Yes, I meant that users should only edit answers on around 5 *questions* at a time. I'll clarify.

Comment: I also agree with this answer, but I suggest that it's recommended to add an edit summary describing why you have edited the text out, to avoid roll backs due to ignorance of the new consensus.

Answer (score 4):

## Edit, and preferably leave a comment

We don't need to ask permission from the author to revoke NC status—it's not within their control anyway (we don't allow users to simply *decide* that their submission should be NC). If it is left there, it constitutes an oversight that should simply be corrected.

That said, it's not particularly important, so try not to let that be your only edit to the post—do it in conjunction with a bunch of other minor edits, or with a larger edit.

Also, as @Mego said, it's a good idea to leave a comment on the answer as well. Something like this might work:

> I've removed the "non-competing" note from your post because [languages postdating the challenge can compete](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/61384).

Comment: Raw source of comment: `I've removed the "non-competing" note from your post because [languages postdating the challenge can compete](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).`

Answer (score 2):

## Leave a comment if the answer postdates the rule change

If the answer is posted *now* that the “non-competing” rule is gone and has been marked as non-competive, that probably means that the author is not aware of the change of rule. In that case leave a comment with a link to the new rule.

It is true that the author doesn't get to decide whether the answer is competing or not but, I wouldn't go as far as editing the answer because of this.

Comment: Posted separately from [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14995/36398) so that people can vote each proposal independently

Comment: "I wouldn't go as far as editing the answer because of this." Why not? If it's done in conjunction with other edits, all you're doing is removing a label that no longer has any meaning (and that we didn't allow them to add anyway).

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I see editing an answer as somewhat intrusive, except for small stuff like typos. I'm not sure this qualifies as small stuff to me

Comment: Is there any potential reason why the user would object to the change?

Comment: It's a significant change, so I think it's better to let the author do it. For example, they may want to remove the "non-competing" note but add a "language postdates the challenge" note. I personally don't agree 100% with the new rule, so leaving a note along those lines may be a good compromise, if the author thinks like I do

Answer (score -3):

## Don't edit if the answer predates the rule change

If the answer *was* non-competing at the time of writing as per the rule that was in force *then*, I see no point in changing it now.

This is similar to how we don't close an old challenge just because it doesn't conform to some current, more stringent rule.

Comment: Posted separately from [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14996/36398) so that people can vote each proposal independently

Comment: "This is similar to how we don't close an old challenge just because it doesn't conform to some current, more stringent rule." Right, except in this case our rules didn't get more *stringent*, they got more *flexible*, which means that the answer would have been competitive had it been posted today. Leaving open historical questions that would have been closed today is arguable, but having NC answers that would have been competing today is imo absurd.