# The Validity of a Custom, General-Purpose Language

Tags: discussion

I am currently writing and maintaining a new general-purpose language, named [CSASM](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM).

I seem to have forgotten the rules surrounding languages such as this one. Hence, it would be preferable to have this question answered beforehand, rather than submit an answer and be embarrassed.

In short, **is it against the rules** to use this language to answer questions?
Since the language is *general-purpose*, the loophole prohibition for languages tailored to do a certain subset of tasks shouldn't apply here, but I'm not certain about the other rules the consensus agrees upon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [You may use it](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)

Almost four years ago, we updated our rules, so now, so long as it's pretty clear you're not exploting this rule (since that is still a violation of the loopholes anyway, like you mentioned), you may use newer languages to answer older questions.

No need to add any indication that it's a newer language. You may just use it to write answers. Have fun :)