# Are there minimum age requirements for languages?

Tags: support, languages

I'm working on my custom golfing language [Hussy.Net](https://github.com/tacosontitan/Hussy.Net), built on top of C#, to address a lot of its pitfalls around verbosity:

```cs
R(10).F(EV).E(W);

                     // Breakdown
                     // ==============================================
R(10).               // Create a collection of integers from 1 to 10.
      F(             // Filter the collection.
        EV).         // Check each value for clean divisibility by 2.
            E(       // Iterate over each value.
              W);    // Write the value to a new line.
```

As the language progresses, I'd like to start using it in challenges to test it out in a more thorough manner.

However, given that I just started working on it earlier this week, and I'm a good way away from the initial release, I'm curious as to when it becomes eligible for usage with answers here. IIRC, the official stance is that I can't use features from a language if they didn't exist before the challenge was created, but is that the only requirement?

For example, can I use the features it has today in a challenge created tomorrow, or does it have to be tied to an officially released version?

---

Are there any other minimum age requirements for using a language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No (there are not)

We used to have a policy that answers with languages that were newer than the challenge could not be considered competing, but this requirement has since been removed since it was doing more harm than good ([source](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)).

As long as you aren't creating built-ins specifically for the challenge, it shouldn't be a problem. We have standard loopholes against things that obviously violate the spirit of healthy competition but your language and features you use do not need to predate the challenge.